# Syntax error - Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm trying to build JS react project with decorators. My .babelrc looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",

  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```

Adding  @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators problems appears again.

I am using babel 7, webpack 4 and react 16.5

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const componentName = "reports-desktop";
const publicFolderRelativePath = "../../../../../../public/js";
const ignorePlugin = new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/);

module.exports = {
    entry: './reports-desktop.js'
    ,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, publicFolderRelativePath),
        filename: `${componentName}.js`
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        ignorePlugin
    ]
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "captain",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack -w --mode development --progress --color --display-error-details",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-stage-1": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-stage-2": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.17.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "dropzone": "^5.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-datetime": "^2.15.0",
    "react-dnd": "^5.0.0",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^5.0.1",
    "react-media": "^1.8.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

Am I maybe using @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators wrong? As it says in documentation this should fix my problem, but it still appears.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? The config looks good to me. I would debug what's going on based on the error stack trace.

Comment: No :/ I was trying to update my project to babel 7, but i didn't manage to due to decorators. Problem is that I imported file with decorators, so I didn't have full control over that component. (I couldn't touch that component as other project used it - bad? - Yes)

Comment: npm installing @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators and adding ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }] to my webpack config in the babel plugins section was enough to solve it for me.  I wonder if your .bablerc is not being picked up somehow.  One difference is, I don't have a .baberc and all babel options are specified in my webpack (I used create-react-app and ejected).

Comment: @bpursley 's solution worked for me as well. also ran `npm run eject` first and added the new plugin to `"babel": { "plugins": [ <plugin here> ], "presets": ["react-app"] }`

Answer (score 122):

I had the same problem, but I was able to get it working by running `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` and adding `["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]` to the plugins section in my `.babelrc`.

The plugins section of `.babelrc`, for me, now looks like this:

```
"plugins": [
  ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
]
```

Comment: restart the server. used only  `"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators"`

Comment: Hey would you mind taking a look at this similar issue? I'm using NextJS and Now.sh for deployments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332378/now-sh-build-breaking-due-to-support-for-the-experimental-syntax-decorators-le

Comment: Is there a non-scoped package for plugin-proposal-decorators? I downgraded babel to babel 6 but I need this package to use mobx. All I can find is the scoped versions.

Comment: @wolfsbane, I don't think they have a non-scoped package for this, but I'm currently using `plugin-proposal-decorators` with mobx. The packages that I think are relevant look like this: `"babel-core": "^6.26.3"`, `"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.2"`, `"mobx": "^5.5.1"`.

Comment: When I add that to the plugins, I get this compile error: `ERROR in The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array`

Comment: Oh my bad. I put it in the plugins section of .eslintrc, not .babelrc

Answer (score 19):

First, execute the command:

`npm install  customize-cra react-app-rewired @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators --save`

Create a new file `config-overrides.js` at project root and then execute the following:

```
const { override, addDecoratorsLegacy } = require('customize-cra');
module.exports = override(
 addDecoratorsLegacy()
 );
```

Also, edit your `package.json`file ：

```
"scripts": {
 "start": "react-app-rewired start",
 "build": "react-app-rewired build",
 "test": "react-app-rewired test",
 "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
```

then restart.

Answer (score 16):

Taken from [mobxjs](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1352). If you're still having issues refer to [this](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1352). It helped me.

Example config for babel 7, in decorators legacy mode:

```
//.babelrc

{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
    ]
}
```

Please note that plugin ordering is important, and plugin-proposal-decorators should be the first plugin in your plugin list

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0"
}
```

Non-legacy mode decorators (stage 2) is work in progress, see #1732

Edit: updated config to show the non-beta configuration for babel 7

Comment: Does not work at all. Having both setup in `packages.json` and `.babelrc` changes nothing.

Comment: Did you try doing it in a `babel.config.js`? I was having issues doing it in a `.babelrc` @Janusz'Ivellios'Kamieński

Comment: No, I didn't, because there was no clear explanation on how to do that. There are only some scraps laying around and no one gives complete example even. React itself is quite easy to start working with, but going to webpack/babel/node - oh boy, this is surrealistic what happens there for regular developer.

Anyway: I solved that simply by throwing out my previous configuration and setting up project with recent CRA and used libs. Luckily that worked in my case.

Answer (score 15):

I fixed this with `yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators`

Then I added the following to `babel.config.js` in the `plugins` section:

```
  [
    require('@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators').default,
    {
      legacy: true
    }
  ],
```

Finally I needed to restart my webpack dev server.

---

I haven't tested this but like @christopher bradshaw answers says and according to the babel website if you are using `.babelrc` for configuration then add the following to the `"plugins"` section:

```
  ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
```

Answer (score 10):

If you face this error while using ReactJS with MobX, don't enable decorator syntax, but leverage the MobX's built-in decorate utility to apply decorators to your classes / objects.

Don't:

```
import { observable, computed, action } from "mobx";

class Timer {
  @observable start = Date.now();
  @observable current = Date.now();

  @computed
  get elapsedTime() {
    return this.current - this.start + "milliseconds";
  }

  @action
  tick() {
    this.current = Date.now();
  }
}
```

Do:

```
import { observable, computed, action, decorate } from "mobx";

class Timer {
  start = Date.now();
  current = Date.now();

  get elapsedTime() {
    return this.current - this.start + "milliseconds";
  }

  tick() {
    this.current = Date.now();
  }
}
decorate(Timer, {
  start: observable,
  current: observable,
  elapsedTime: computed,
  tick: action
});
```

Comment: I found this answer most useful!
Also found more on the mobX site: https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html

Comment: This is a workaround, not the actual solution to the problem. It's legitimate to choose not to use decorators, but if you decided you want to use decorator syntax in your code, you should set up the configuration to work with them, not give up up because the magical babel incantation necessary is too obscure.

Comment: @wuliwong's answer to enable Babel to do its job is what we're after: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55985896/1181545

Comment: FIY, the decorate has been removed in MobX 6

Comment: Wohh... Thank you for your explanation. Really helpful. I wasted my 2 days for adapting observable in reactjs and after your answer I tested the scenario and it works.

Answer (score 5):

1. Install decorator in package.json

```
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0",
"@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0"
```

2. update babe.config.js with this

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": [
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset",
    "@babel/preset-flow"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy" : true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose" : true }],
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately none of the mentioned solutions worked for me. Because they need you to run `npm run eject` first and ... I don't want to do that. To change and override the webpack's configs at runtime, there's a package called `react-app-rewired` and this is how it should be used:

First install the required dependencies:

```
npm i --save-dev customize-cra react-app-rewired
```

Then add a new file called `config-overrides.js` to the root folder of the project with this content to enable legacy decorators babel plugin:

```
const {
  override,
  addDecoratorsLegacy,
  disableEsLint
} = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = override(
  // enable legacy decorators babel plugin
  addDecoratorsLegacy(),

  // disable eslint in webpack
  disableEsLint()
);
```

Finally change the `package.json` file to use `react-app-rewired`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
```

Now run the `npm start` as usual and enjoy it!

Answer (score 3):

As of 2021, with Create React App 4.0, only the following steps are required.

1. Make sure you **do not eject**.
2. `npm i --save-dev customize-cra react-app-rewired`
3. Add `config-overrides.js` with:

```js
const { addDecoratorsLegacy, override } = require('customize-cra')

module.exports = override(addDecoratorsLegacy())
```

4. Add `babel.config.js` with:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }]],
}
```

5. Open `package.json` / scripts section and search-replace `react-scripts` -> `react-app-rewired`.

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-app-rewired start",
  "build": "react-app-rewired build",
  "test": "react-app-rewired test",
}
```

After this, both `start`, `build`, and `test` commands will work with the codebase.

Comment: Solved it for me; I am no longer getting any errors :)

Answer (score 2):

package.json

```
"@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.5"
```

webpack.config.js

```
presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins":  [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To use **Mobx** with **Babel** in 2020...

## 1

```
npm i babel-preset-mobx
```

## 2

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['other-presets', 'mobx'],
};
```

So, just install the `mobx` preset and add it to your babel configuration file inside the `presets` array. For example in a `babel.config.js` etc.

Comment: perfect, should be the accepted answer from now :) @olga-babic

Comment: This package seems abandoned for 3 years now, I wouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install `babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables` and it worked.

```
npm install babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables
```

Answer (score 0):

Renamed `.babelrc` to `babel.config.json` and **it worked**!!!

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021,if you've already “run Eject”,to edit the file called "babelTransform" under the path "/config/jest/BabelTransform",like this:

```
...
module.exports = babelJest.createTransformer({
  presets: [
    [
      require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app'),
      {
        runtime: hasJsxRuntime ? 'automatic' : 'classic',
      },
    ],
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true,
      }
    ]
  ],
  babelrc: false,
  configFile: false,
});
...
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this steps and it worked:

1.

> ```
> npm i --save-dev customize-cra react-app-rewired @babel/plugin-proposal-
>         decorators
> ```

2. create in the rro directory config-overrides.js and this is:

> ```
> const { addDecoratorsLegacy, override } = require('customize-cra')
> module.exports = override(addDecoratorsLegacy())
> ```

3. edit package.json scripts

> ```
> "scripts": {
>     "start": "react-app-rewired start",
>     "build": "react-app-rewired build",
>     "test": "react-app-rewired test",
>     "eject": "react-scripts eject"   
>  },
> ```

All credits go to this article: https://www.tderflinger.com/en/litelement-react-app