# Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, mobx, mobx-react

I am getting the above error when I am using mobx-react and while trying to use annotations.Here I am using .js and not .ts. All the solutions provided earlier not successful for me.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';

@inject('authStore')
@withRouter
@observer
class Login extends Component {

   componentWillUnmount() {
       this.props.authStore.reset();
   }

}
```

My error is
[image]

Comment: This is a webpack configuration issue is addressed in several other questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52765213/609021 for how to configure your .babelrc

Answer (score 1):

If you are using babel then you need to install and use `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` with `legacy` mode enabled.

For example, plugins section of `.babelrc`:

```
    "plugins": [
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
    ]
```