# Now.sh build breaking due to: Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, decorator, babeljs, next.js

### Expected:

After adding `decko` (Support for decorators) as well as adding support for `experimetalDecoractors` in my **tsconfig.js** and using `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` in **package.json**.

My [now.sh](https://zeit.co/now) build should build and deploy fine after creating a PR, also since the app is running perfectly locally.

### Results:

The build actually breaks with the following error:

[image]

> Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled

**PR:** https://github.com/Futuratum/moonholdings.io/pull/27

**Build:** https://zeit.co/leongaban/moonholdings/9aacr3qhs

---

I actually had this same error locally, however I fixed it by adding the `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` package and updating my package.json like so:

```
"babel": {
    "env": {
      "development": {
        "presets": [
          "next/babel"
        ],
        "plugins": [
          [
            "styled-components",
            {
              "ssr": true,
              "displayName": true
            }
          ],
          [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
            {
              "legacy": true
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
```

I also tried moving the babel config out into the .bablerc file and my build still breaks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out, I needed to add the plugin to the `production` part of my config for the build to work X_x

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": [
        "next/babel",
        "@zeit/next-typescript/babel"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "styled-components",
          {
            "ssr": true,
            "displayName": true
          }
        ],
        [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
          {
            "legacy": true
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "production": {
      "presets": [
        "next/babel",
        "@zeit/next-typescript/babel"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "styled-components",
          {
            "ssr": true,
            "displayName": true
          }
        ],
        [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
          {
            "legacy": true
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
```

Comment: Good catch! Glad you were able to figure it out!

Answer (score 3):

Note for Next.JS NX users, there is currently an open (12/2020) [issue](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/3322) for this error on their github at: github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/3322

I have tried to fix this problem using several solutions in combination, but have not succeeded yet.

Answer (score 0):

i'm seeing something similar on my end, but i think you can do this:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]],
  "env": {...}
}
```

Seems like you can have global plugins for all the things, vs setting it all up for each one. would be yawnsome otherwise.