# Is there a problem when use of mobx in my project , the error is 'Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled'

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I configured my package.json and babelrc but I got some errors when I used decorators.

I use "react16.8.1" and "mobx5.9.4".

My babelrc code:

````
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react",

    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
        [
           "@babel/plugin-decorators-legacy",
            {
          "legacy": true
            }
        ],


    ]
}```
and my package.json
````

```
{
  "name": "material-dashboard-pro-react",
  "version": "1.5.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "3.9.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "3.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "chartist": "0.10.1",
    "history": "4.7.2",
    "mobx": "^5.9.4",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.8.3",
    "node-sass": "4.11.0",
    "nouislider": "13.1.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.4.0",
    "rc-pagination": "^1.17.13",
    "react": "16.8.1",
    "react-big-calendar": "0.20.3",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "4.4.1",
    "react-chartist": "0.13.3",
    "react-datetime": "2.16.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.1",
    "react-google-maps": "9.4.5",
    "react-hichestan-datetimepicker": "^0.2.12",
    "react-jvectormap": "0.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "react-select": "^2.4.2",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.13.1",
    "react-table": "6.9.2",
    "react-tagsinput": "3.19.0",
    "react-toastify": "^5.0.0",
    "simple-react-modal": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "npm run build",
    "lint:check": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx;  exit 0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx --fix;  exit 0",
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.30.16",
    "@types/markerclustererplus": "2.1.33",
    "ajv": "6.9.1",
    "prettier": "1.16.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-preset-mobx": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.0.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app",
      "mobx"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-decorators-legacy",
         {
           "legacy": true
         }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

I used it before and it was working fine but after upgrading react and mobx, I get this error: "Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled"

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53746840/829154

Comment: yeah i know , yesterday i solved it , i used mobx utility and every thing work fine , I think this problem related to mobx, but it depend on babel ! because  I think babel 7 cannot support decorators based on this issue in github https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues/234