# Mobx and React. No support for experimental syntax

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have problem with Mobx syntax. This is my first project with Mobx.

I've got message: "Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled"

What shoud I do? How should syntax look? Or syntax is good and I should do this: [Syntax error - Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52262084/syntax-error-support-for-the-experimental-syntax-decorators-legacy-isnt-cur/53746840#53746840)

My store:

```
import React from 'react';
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

class VehicleStore {
    @observable makeInput = React.createRef();
    @observable modelInput = React.createRef();
    @observable imageInput = React.createRef();
    @observable isSorted = false;
    @observable newId = React.createRef();
    @observable newMake = React.createRef();
    @observable newModel = React.createRef();
    @observable newImage = React.createRef();

    @observable cars = [
        { id: "0", VehicleMake: "Hyundai", VehicleModel: "i30", image:"https://p7.hiclipart.com/preview/240/803/583/hyundai-motor-company-car-hyundai-i30-go-hyundai-tucson-hyundai-i30.jpg" },
        { id: "1", VehicleMake: "Volkswagen", VehicleModel: "Golf (Mk8)", image:"https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/OYNeX/s3/volkswagen-golf-8-2019.jpg" },
        { id: "2", VehicleMake: "Škoda", VehicleModel: "Octavia (Mk4) Combi", image: "https://360view.hum3d.com/zoom/Skoda/Skoda_Octavia_Mk4_combi_2020_1000_0001.jpg" },
        { id: "3", VehicleMake: "BMW", VehicleModel: "M340i xDrive", image: "https://the-drive.imgix.net/https%3A%2F%2Fapi.thedrive.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2018%2F11%2Fp90323745_highres_the-all-new-bmw-3-se-e1542124443158.jpg%3Fquality%3D85?w=1440&auto=compress%2Cformat&ixlib=js-1.4.1&s=4c3c15eb72a86204b03b02a0569d969b" },
        { id: "4", VehicleMake: "Mercedes", VehicleModel: "C63", image: "https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/711x295/https://blogs-images.forbes.com/dougnewcomb/files/2018/05/Exterior.jpg?width=960" },
        { id: "5", VehicleMake: "Citroen", VehicleModel: "C4 Picasso", image: "https://i7.pngguru.com/preview/663/741/68/citroen-c4-picasso-car-citroen-ds-citroen-c4-cactus-citroen.jpg" },
        { id: "6", VehicleMake: "Hyundai", VehicleModel: "Tuscon", image:"https://www.irwinhyundai.com/assets/stock/colormatched_01/white/640/cc_2020hys02_01_640/cc_2020hys020105_01_640_r2u.jpg?height=400" }, 
        { id: "7", VehicleMake: "Škoda", VehicleModel: "Superb", image: "https://d3h256n3bzippp.cloudfront.net/skoda-superb-iv-white-background.jpg" },
        { id: "8", VehicleMake: "BMW", VehicleModel: "M4", image: "https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/154-1541467_new-2020-bmw-m4-coupe-bmw-m4-2019.png" },
        { id: "9", VehicleMake: "Toyota", VehicleModel: "C-HR", image: "https://cdn-ds.com/blogs-media/sites/232/2019/10/07162921/WhatE28099s-New-for-the-2020-Toyota-C-HR-Design_o.jpg" },
        {id: "10", VehicleMake: "Volkswagen", VehicleModel: "Passat", image: "https://www.greeleyvolkswagen.com/assets/stock/colormatched_01/white/640/cc_2020vwc04_01_640/cc_2020vwc040002_01_640_0q0q.jpg?height=400"},
        {id: "10", VehicleMake: "Volkswagen", VehicleModel: "Tiguan", image: "https://p7.hiclipart.com/preview/98/115/693/2018-volkswagen-tiguan-car-sport-utility-vehicle-volkswagen-eos-2018.jpg"},
        {id: "11", VehicleMake: "Škoda", VehicleModel: "Fabia Estate", image: "https://cdn1.carbuyer.co.uk/sites/carbuyer_d7/files/car_images/skoda-fabia-estate-2018-cutout.jpg"},
        {id: "12", VehicleMake: "Ford", VehicleModel: "Mondeo", image: "https://purepng.com/public/uploads/medium/purepng.com-ford-mondeo-red-carcarvehicletransportford-96152463841846uwj.png"},
        {id: "13", VehicleMake: "Audi", VehicleModel: "A5 Sportback", image: "https://images.dealer.com/ddc/vehicles/2020/Audi/S5/Hatchback/color/Daytona%20Gray%20Pearl%20Effect-6Y6Y-70,72,68-640-en_US.jpg"},
        {id: "14", VehicleMake: "Hyundai", VehicleModel: "i20", image: "https://images.livemint.com/rf/Image-621x414/LiveMint/Period1/2014/10/11/Photos/car--621x414.jpg"},
        {id: "15", VehicleMake: "Audi", VehicleModel: "Q7", image: "https://pictures.dealer.com/aoa-images/42f3217ec5c4c42feeb7fae938ba6396.png"}
    ]

    //Add new car
    @action addCar = ({id, VehicleMake, VehicleModel, image}) => {
    this.cars.push({
        id: ++this.lastId, 
        VehicleMake: this.newMake.current.value, 
        VehicleModel: this.newModel.current.value,
        image: this.newImage.current.value
    })
}}

const store = new VehicleStore()

export default store
```

And my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import VehicleStore from './stores/VehicleStore.js';

const Root = (
    <Provider VehicleStore={VehicleStore}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(Root, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `npm run eject` this will copy all the configuration files and the transitive dependencies (Webpack, Babel, ESLint, etc) right into your project so you can modify them.
Then, you will need to modify Babel configuration and add [babel plugin transform decorators](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/babel-plugin-transform-decorators) to your babel configuration.

Or you can use alternative syntax for mobx

```js
import { observable,action, decorate } from "mobx"

decorate(VehicleStore,{
   makeInput:observable,
   modelInput:observable,
   addCar:action
   // etc....
)
```

Check out the [mobx documentation](https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html)

Also, mobx in `V6` will most likely [drop support for decorators](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/2325), at least until the spec for them stabilizes.

Comment: I did npm run eject. And edited .babelrc file. Now my app is shown properly. I need to finish everything. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `create-react-app`, I believe that decorators are only supported when using typescript.

Comment: Yeah, I used create-react-app. How can I fix this now?

Comment: Many thanks for this. I will try it. So what I should do better,  eject and edit config or use decorators and change syntax?