# How to Enable Private Method Syntax Proposal in React App?

Tags: babeljs, babel-plugin, ecmascript-2019

I got "Class private methods are not enabled." error when running `npm start` on a project using leading # to indicate private methods.
I followed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55822103/4258041 to enable the decorator and it worked, but I cannot find corresponding `customize-cra` components to add private method syntax in a same way.
`"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.14.5"` is already installed and saved in my packages.json.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties.
Install with

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```

then add it to your .babelrc plugin section:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

Please consider that while I'm writing this is already an outdated answer, since Class Fields [are no longer a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/main/finished-proposals.md) since ES2022 and this plugin is included in @babel/preset-env.

See [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) for further information.

Comment: some instructions how to enable the @babel/preset-env would be nice...