# 'Class private methods are not enabled' in React

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I am new to React and am trying to run a program from GitHub. I try to use `npm start`, but the compiler throw out a problem saying that "Class private methods are not enabled. Please add `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods` to your configuration.".
[image: error]

I tried to use `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods`. Also I created a .babelrc in the root directory of this project(I don't know wether this operation is correct since I know nothing about React). This is my .babelrc.
[image: .babelrc]

Also I have tried [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68686444/how-to-enable-private-method-syntax-proposal-in-react-app](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), but it seems not working.

I am confused and I appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: Also here looking for a solution. This started when I upgraded react-native from 0.69.4 to 0.71.8 (plus all the dependant packages updated)

Comment: I haven't found solution for this problem, the only way to go through it for me  is to avoid using babel.